# ImportError: No module named pyplot (even after installing matplotlib)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to import matplotlib like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

For this I have installed matplotlib using.

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Although the `basic_example.py` from [the examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) worked, it suddenly stopped running along with all other files with matplotlib giving me the below error:

```
File "matplotlib.py", line 2, in <module>
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # pyplot module.
ImportError: No module named pyplot`
```

I tried to check if the module is still there, and it seems to be. What could be possibly wrong?

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,>=1.5.6 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil->matplotlib)`
```

I am using Windows and Python 2.7.

Comment: What happens when you run `import matplotlib`

Comment: Why's there a grave accent in ``ImportError: No module named pyplot` `` o_o

Comment: @TedPetrou same error.    

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # pyplot module.
ImportError: No module named pyplot

Comment: @moogle That grave accent seems to be just the result of someone's edit. Not related to the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2.7 tries to find modules in the current working directory first, before going into the installed packages, so because you named your test file "matplotlib.py", it will interpret it as the matplotlib package. Rename your test file to something else, and it should be fine